# Print counts of levels in rows with the same value in a column

Tags: r, count

Say I have a dataframe `df`:

```
c1   c2
A    porcupine
A    snail
A    snail
B    porcupine
B    snail
B    goose
```

I want to use this dataframe to generate another that reports the counts of different values in `c2` that correspond to a unique string in `c1`. So, given the example above, it would look something like this:

```
v1   v2
A    2
B    3
```

since there were only two different values in `c2` that had "A" as the string in `c1` and there were three different values in `c2` that had "B" in `c1`.

I'm guessing I need to use sapply but I'm not sure how.

Comment: with `dplyr`, `df %>%
  group_by(c1) %>%
  summarise(v2 = n_distinct(c2))
` Or using base R `aggregate(c2~c1, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: @Ronak Shah: Sorry for my almost identical answer, I was identifying traffic lights in the recaptcha box which made my answer arrive late..

Comment: @Lennyy No issues, one should always follow "traffic lights" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(c2 ~ c1, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))

  c1 c2
1  A  2
2  B  3
```